# How can I use multiple math fonts?

Tags: fonts, greek, mathdesign, amsfonts

I'm using `mathdesign` package.
Most features including greek fonts are satisfactory, however its alphabet math fonts look ugly.
`amsfonts` package has standard good-looking fonts but its greek fonts are ugly.
So I want to use `mathdesign` package with *ams* alphabet math fonts but they have conflict.

How can I use two different font packages?

------ Additional Question ---

Now I try to use GreekMathSymbols fonts for Greek symbol only.

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setsansfont{Clear Sans}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont{GreekMathSymbols.ttf}[range=bfsfit/{greek,Greek}]
```

It works fine with Greek symbols
But I want latin modern math for latin and numbers so I tried this one

```
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math.otf}
\setmathfont{GreekMathSymbols.ttf}[range=bfsfit/{greek,Greek}]
```

This time, Greek Symbols are changed to default fonts
with following error message

**
*Font "GreekMathSymbols" does not contain requested(fontspec) Script "Math".*

When the main math font is Asana Math, there was no such an error.

---

I found the answer

GreekMathSymbols.ttf doesn't have a math table - so I changed it to STIX Two Math

`\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range=bfsfit/{greek,Greek}]`

it didn't work,

option `bfsfit` should be changed to `\mathit`

finally

```
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range=\mathit/{greek,Greek}]
```

it works as I wanted

In unicod-math manual there is no explanation about `\mathit` option when selecting font range

Answer (score 1):

Use Unicode fonts. Then you can choose really beautiful ones, there are multiple for any taste. You also will be able to mix fonts for different Unicode ranges.

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, paper = B5]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}[range = \mdlgwhtsquare]
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I'll try. only problem is that these packages do not support PdfLatex.

Comment: If you don't have a very serious reason to use pdftex, switch to LuaTeX.

Comment: pdftex is really just for legacy 8-bit fonts from last century.

Comment: thank you for your comments. Pdflatex is a little faster when building but I'll move to LualaTex

Comment: It's a very bold statement, and doesn't make sense without context given. Both engines use the same code for the TeX part. In general, if a package is implemented in Lua, it will be several times faster, than the same implemented in pure TeX. Moreover, because of TeX limitations, for certain functionality you must save intermediate results and run a TeX engine several times to achieve a goal. If something is implemented in Lua, you don't need to compile the same document sometimes 5 times over an over. Nowadays, more and more packages are switching to Lua.

Comment: I'm sorry I have very little experience in using Xetex or Luatex, so first impression was error messages and long loading time.

Comment: There are some TeX distros that have LuaTeX super slow. For example, MikTeX on Windows. Not LuaTeX fault, though.

Comment: I tried to use unicode-math but I still have problems. There is something I'm missing. I added questions

Comment: I don't know of any journals, or any major publishers, that allow submissions in LuaLaTeX.  Pdflatex has the advantage for work that you want to publish.

Comment: LaTex packages have no consistent grammar. Their options have conflicts occasionally. There always be creative solutions but they are not consistent. Divergent developement is good for the creative evolution, but beginners like me need consistency

Comment: I wish LaTex3 could set up consistent grammar unifying XeTeX, LuaTeX, expl3 etc